# Find shortest path to visit a number of towns

Tags: algorithm

I came across this problem and didn't know how to solve it. Can someone please help me with this?

There are n towns connected by n-1 roads, and there is a road between any 2 towns. Each road has a positive associated cost.The country's city C has 2 roads connected to it (the city is also one of the towns), and each other town has 1 or 3 roads connected to it.

We want to start a trip from city C, visit m different towns (1 <= m <= n), and come back to C. However, we might need to backtrack our trip to visit m towns. Give an algorithm to find the shortest path that visits m different towns.

Comment: Sounds like the travelling salesman problem, it is supposed to be extremely difficult to solve

Comment: There are only n-1 roads? So this is a tree? .... and it is in fact a Binary tree rooted at C, if I understand everything else you have said? You should be able to exploit that data structure somehow.

Comment: Yes it's a tree.  But it's not so obvious and should be proved using the fact that there cannot be cycles in a graph where there is at most $n-1$ edges and there are $n$ vertices which are all adjacent to at least one edge.  **edit**:  You must require the graph to be conected i.e. each city is reachable from another.

Answer (score 3):

This graph is a [Binary Tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_tree) with root C.

I think out an `O(n^3)` algorithm, mainly use [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)

`dp[i][j]`stores the value of the shortest path for `i-th`towns, visit `j` different towns in its subtree. We can easily find the equation that

`dp[i][j] = min (dp[sonl][k] + dp[sonr][j-k-1] + 2*wl + 2*wr | 1<=k<=j-1)`

It means that visitting `k` towns in left subtree and `j-k-1`towns in right subtree.`sonl` and `sonr` are two sons of `i-th` town, `wl`and`wr`are the distance between `i` to `sonl`and`sonr`

Comment: I think a town could have 1 or 3 children, but your solution assumes it has 2 children. Can we do a check to see how many children it has, then use a corresponding formula to calculate dp[i][j] ?

Comment: @CsIsFun We can treat city C as root, so all other node has two children except leaf

Comment: But we only have 1 root with 2 children. I think other nodes should have 1 or 3 children

Comment: `each other town has 1 or 3 roads connected to it` contains its father

Answer (score 2):

Read the wikipedia artice: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem
It's an np-hard problem, which means that your solution will be slow. It's not unsolvable, you can easily solve it, if you have infinite time. The simplest algorithm is calculating every possible path that starts and ends with the starting city, their weights and get the lowest. This is the stupidest possible way, and probably the most computationally expensive.

Normally such problems are solved using linear programming formulation (not to be confused with computer programming/coding), although I would recommend using a heuristic way. Doing a google search on "tsp genetic algorithm" will give you various articles on, imho, the best way to solve this problem. It's an extremely stupid and clever algorithm at the same time, and it's fast, REALLY fast. The only problem is that the solution is not optimal*. If you want to know the optimal solution, then you need to check for the optimality conditions of the problem (in your case, having the lowest cost of any possible path).

If you want to satisfy the optimality condition, then it becomes much harder to solve quickly, ergo the NP-Hard classification.

(notice that that the simplest way - calculating every path - is inferred by the optimality condition, although there could be a smarter way of being sure that your calculated path is optimal. If you find a better optimality condition for this problem, call the journalists, you're going to make headlines. Good luck.)

*if you want a "good" answer, like a really low cost path, but not necessarily the lowest possible, then Genetic Algorithms are, imho, the way to go.

Comment: The graph described by this question appears to be a tree. This is not a general TSP and is quite likely to be solvable in polynomial time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that if the graph is connected the best chance is to create a spanning tree included inside the graph. You can do it with the Pirm algorithm. This way you can easily find the shortest path between each city.

[for more informations](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm)